# JavaScript Alert Selected Option of html drop down

Tags: javascript, html

I have searched around and tried various things but I cannot find a way to get javascript to alert my chosen option. All that happens with what I have is in the console debugging section at the bottom of the page it says " 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'x.options') " which suggests to me that my variable x is not getting any value in the first place, here is my code:

html

```
    <select id=“test-dropdown” onchange=“choice1()”>

    <option value=“1”>One</option>

    <option value=“2”>Two</option>

    <option value=“3”>Three</option>

    </select>
```

javascript

```
    function choice1()
    {
    var x = document.getElementById(“test-dropdown”);
    alert(x.options[x.selectedIndex].value);
    }
```

I would be very thankful if someone could solve the problem or point me in the direction of where this question has been answered before.

Comment: Duplicate but -- not all browsers fire a change event when you think they would....  I tend to bind to both `change` and `click` to make sure both are covered.

Comment: There seems to be some problem in encoding your code.  your code is working fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/7K4AK/  Better type the whole code to avoid UTF encoding.

Comment: thanks it seems as its on my mac speech marks don't work properly unless copied. took your script and it worked fine.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I believe you want to alert the text of the chosen element, you can do it by doing this in a shorter way too

HTML:

```
<select id="test-dropdown" onchange="choice1(this)">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

JavaScript:

```
function choice1(select) {
     alert(select.options[select.selectedIndex].text);
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AwFE3/

Answer (score -1):

Try below code :  [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hq7Ah/5/)

```
$( "select" )
.change(function () {
var str = "";
$( "select option:selected" ).each(function() {
str += $( this ).text() + " ";
});
alert(str)
})
```

Comment: `jQuery` is a helper library build on JS and also OP haven't tagged it under `jQuery`.